# Autolinking dependencies in React Native

Tags: react-native

## Context

I have a couple of React Native apps which share some components and helpers.
So I created a library to store the shared code, and I use it in my apps by adding it as a dependency in the respective `package.json`.

Inside my custom library, I use `react-native.config.js` to link some fonts

```
module.exports = {
  assets: ['./assets/fonts']
};
```

And in my apps, I do `npx react-native link my-custom-library` to link these fonts.

Now, this shared library is also using [react-native-community/react-native-localize](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-localize).
And I don't know how to link it in my apps

## I have 2 questions here:

- Why do I need to do `npx react-native link my-custom-library` for the fonts?
  Shouldn't **React Native 60**'s autolinking feature do this for me automatically?
- How can link `react-native-localize` using this setup?

Comment: Hi @David, I updated my answer, please let me know if that works. The answer has been tested by me in RN 0.61.4

Answer (score 0):

**1) About the fonts for RN 0.60+:**

- you should have a `react-native.config.js`

with a content like this:

```
module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {},
  assets: ['./src/assets/fonts', 'react-native-vector-icons'],
  // Add the rn-vector icons in the above array only if you use that module, or your <libraryName> too.
};
```

- Run react-native link and you should see a log like this:

> info Linking assets to ios project info Linking assets to android
>
> project success Assets have been successfully linked to your project

- Add the fonts in Info.plist file:

  ```
  <key>UIAppFonts</key>
  <array>
   <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
   <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
   <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
   <string>Feather.ttf</string>
   <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
   <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
   <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
   <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
   <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
   <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
   <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
   <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
   <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
   <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
   <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
  </array>
  ```
- Check `Run Script Only When Installing` in `Xcode->YourProjectTarget->BuildPhases-> Copy Pods Resources`
- Make sure you clean all the cache:

`rm -rf $TMPDIR/react- && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro- && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-* && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf ios/build` and restart JS server.

Source and more info here:

https://medium.com/@mehran.khan/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4

I couldn't make the fonts work without the react-native link command and it seems that other people encountered this issue too.

**2) About the `react-native-localize`**

If you already linked it manually just run `react-native unlink react-native-localize` and then go to `ios` folder and run a `pod install`.

The line `use_native_modules` (from `Podfile`) will make the pod installer search for a pod spec file (`RNLocalize.podspec`) in the library folder from node_modules and install it and link it automatically.

**Notes:**

- This answer has been tested in RN 0.61.4 on iOS simulator
- Hints how to link a library that provides fonts I found here:

https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1041